# MySQL not using index for ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I've a simple MySQL table named 'test' with two columns:

1. Auto incrementing int column called 'id'
2. Varchar(3000) column called 'textcol'

I create an index in the table based on the 'textcol' column. However, the ORDER BY query doesn't seem to be using the index i.e. the EXPLAIN statement on a simple query with ORDER BY on textcol shows NULL in the Key column in its output and also uses filesort.

Any pointers to make changes to help use the index for the ORDER by query will be useful to me.

MySQL version as given by "mysql --version' command:

**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.58, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), textcol VARCHAR(3000));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE test;
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| textcol | varchar(3000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE INDEX textcolindex ON test (textcol);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM test;
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| test  |          1 | textcolindex |            1 | textcol     | A         |        NULL |     1000 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (textcol) VALUES ('test1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (textcol) VALUES ('test2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (textcol) VALUES ('test3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (textcol) VALUES ('test4');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)


mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY textcol;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Are you continuing to see this with lots of data in the table? Explain doesn't tell you what it will always do with this query, only what it would do with this query at this moment.

Comment: I changed the size of the textcol column to 10 bytes and inserted 30000 new rows. The ORDER BY in SELECT * still doesn't use the index. However, I just noticed that a SELECT COUNT(*) statement uses the index. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it has to load the entire table to answer the query and sorting 4 elements is cheap, the query optimizer might just be avoiding touching the index.  Does it still happen with larger tables?

Note that a varchar(3000) column can't be a covering index because MySQL won't include more than the first 768 or so bytes of a varchar in an index.

If you want the query to only read the index, the index must have every column you're `SELECT`ing for in it.  On innodb, that should start working for your two-column table once you make textcol small enough; on MyISAM you'll need to include the primary key column yourself, like `CREATE INDEX textcolindex ON test (textcol,id);`

Comment: I changed the size of the textcol column to 10 bytes and inserted 30000 new rows. The ORDER BY in SELECT * still doesn't use the index. However, I just noticed that a SELECT COUNT(*) statement uses the index. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: To clarify, indexes are 1000 byte limit for MyISAM and 767 for InnoDB, far shy of 3000 varchar field. In effect, MySQL will use an index prefix, which can be used to aid seeking (eg. WHERE clauses), but it cannot be used for sorting, since it is incomplete: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: @Kowshik, without a "covering" index, MySQL would have to do 30,000 seeks to utilize the index. A filesort is still easier than 30,000 seeks. Try `SELECT textcol ORDER BY textcol` instead.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: I see. Thanks for the info. Is there any way at all by which I could speed up a : "SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY X" query?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Yes, `SELECT textcol ORDER BY textcol` uses the index! Also if I create a different index that comprises of all the columns, then the `SELECT *` statement uses the index. :)

Comment: @Kowshik: ah you beat me to my edit.  I take it you're using MyISAM and not innoDB?  They use indexes differently so optimizations that work for one don't necessarily work for the other.

Comment: @BCoates: I'm not sure which one I'm using. I checked /etc/mysql/my.cnf but it doesn't clearly indicate which one is enabled. How can I find out?

Answer (score 9):

Some useful articles on ORDER BY optimisation:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

http://opsmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/mysql-query-optimization-for-order-by.html

As largely discussed, keep the varchar down to 767 and add a key for the order by:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
textcol VARCHAR(767),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
KEY orderby (`textcol`)
);
```

To avoid `filesorts` if adding extra 'WHERE' parameters, extend the 'orderby' index key using a multiple column index:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
tom INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
gerry INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
textcol VARCHAR(767),
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
KEY orderby (`tom`,`gerry`, `textcol`)
);
```

Also:

```
INSERT INTO test (tom, gerry, textcol) VALUES (1,2,'test4');
INSERT INTO test (tom, gerry, textcol) VALUES (1,2,'test2');
EXPLAIN SELECT id, textcol FROM test WHERE tom = 1 AND gerry =2 ORDER BY textcol;
```

Extra: 'Using where; Using Index'

Comment: Thanks for the links. Though old, they were helpful

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem. MySQL is stupid. fyi: I have a table with more than 500,000,000 records. I wanted to to:

```
select * from table order by tid limit 10000000, 10;
```

tid is the primary key in the table and is automatically indexed by mysql.

This took a long time and I cancelled the query. then I let mysql "explain" the query and recognized that it won't use the index for the primary key. after reading many docs from mysql i tried to force mysql to use the index via "USE INDEX(...)" and dis also did not work. Then I rocognized that mysql seems to always correlate the where clause with the order by clause. So I tried to extend the where clause with a condition with touches the index. I ended up with:

```
select * from table use index (PRIMARY) where tid > 0 order by tid limit 10000000, 10;
```

where tid is the primary key in the table and is an autoincrement value which starts at 1.

This worked after I let mysql explain the query to me. And behold: the query took only 4 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. This may come handy someday