# How to implement MySql Indexes in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7

Just started learning about MySql indexes. So, I apologize in advance if you think its a silly question.

Just wanna know do you index `slug` column, if yes please share how you implement that And also share should we index `slug` or not.

My 2nd question is, in query builder if we use the method `latest()` to fetch the latest record it uses `created_at` column to sort that. So, should we also index `created_at` column. I asked this question because I think we can also sort the latest record using the `id` column and because it is the primary key so it is already index. So, it does not need to index the `created_at` column as well. What do you think?

Comment: Any column that you would specify in a where clause is a good candidate for indexing provided that it has high cardinality. Check laravel documentation's db migration section to learn more about indexing migrations. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#indexes

Comment: As for id and created_at, id's may not always be in order, however rare it maybe, so it's logical to sort based on created_at. About indexing order by, mysql seems to put you in tight positions, a simple explanation might not be enough. Do please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641463/mysql-not-using-index-for-order-by

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. If you will use the `slug` in search conditions, you should index the field. Do something like this:

```php
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $blueprint) {
            $blueprint->string('slug')->index('articles-slug');
        });
```

2. As far as I know, laravel uses `created_at` column for `latest()` method and it does not index it by it's own.