# ORDER BY clause slows down query

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables.

**Products:**

[image]

**Assets:**

[image]

Result with ORDER BY clause return in 44 seconds.

```
SELECT p.id, i.filepath, p.TotalDownloads 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN assets i ON i.hash=p.product_id 
WHERE p.Name like '%rar%' AND i.format='ico' 
ORDER by p.TotalDownloads DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10

Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 44.0769 seconds.) [TotalDownloads: 164554096... - 724290...]
```

AND without ORDER BY clause, results return in 1 second.

```
SELECT p.id, i.filepath, p.TotalDownloads 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN assets i ON i.hash=p.product_id 
WHERE p.Name like '%rar%' AND i.format='ico' 
LIMIT 0, 10

Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 1.0668 seconds.)
```

Indexes:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are your indexes & execution plan?

Comment: Sort of makes sense as `ORDER BY` requires actual sorting of result set rather than taking 10 random/first results (see execution plans for both queries). On the other hand perhaps adding and index would help as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641463/mysql-not-using-index-for-order-by ?

Comment: What is total selected rows amount, without LIMIT?

Comment: I have added indexes.

Comment: @Akina 733 total, Query took 44.1317 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `LONGTEXT` if you don't need it.  Have you ever seen a "name" with millions of characters?  `VARCHAR(100)` is probably overkill.  Also, why is "price" not some numeric datatype?

To make use of the following index suggestions, you must avoid any form of `TEXT` if possible.

My index recommendations are:

```
p:  INDEX(product_id, Name, TotalDownloads,  id)
p:  INDEX(TotalDownloads,  Name, product_id, id)
p:  INDEX(Name, product_id, TotalDownloads,  id)
i:  INDEX(format, hash,  filepath)
```

I list multiple arrangements for `p`; simply add all of them and let the Optimizer pick which to use.  It may even use a different for different data values.

All of those are "covering", which gives *some* performance boost.

The main drawback in optimizing the query is that the `WHERE` has limitations on both tables.  The Optimizer cannot necessarily decide which table to start with.  Or it might decide to start with the `ORDER BY` instead; this saves a sort.

Since there is no one index to get all the way through the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, all the possible rows must be gathered, then sorted, and finally 10 delivered.

Since you may need a longer "filepath" than indexing would allow, leave it as `TEXT` and remove it from my index suggestion.

Comment: Thanks man. Converted p.Name to Varchar(100) and added the first three indexes. Now results return in 2.3 seconds.